# How do I do this complex analysis question?

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Find the image of the following region under the mapping $w = \frac{1}{z}: \mid z-1 \mid =1$.
I know there's a quick method in that $\mid w -1 \mid = \mid w \mid$. But I'm getting the other method wrong shown below. 
Since $\mid z - 1 \mid =1$. We let $z=x+iy$. This means $x^2+y^2=2x$.
Now $z=\frac{1}{w}=\frac{u-iv}{u^2+v^2}$. Let $w=u+iv$. This means that
$x =\frac{u}{u^2+v^2}$ and $y=\frac{-v}{u^2+v^2}$. 
This means $\frac{u^2+v^2}{u^2+v^2}=\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2}=1$. This is a circle. So what did I do wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It's impossible to make sense of your post because you never told us what "this complex analysis question" might be!

Comment: Sorry I put the question now above.

Comment: OK, so $|w|=|w-1|$ if you know that $|z-1|=1$. Now that makes sense. And you should say "Let $w=u+iv$" before you write $z=1/w = \dots$. At any rate, in your final computations, you forgot to square $u^2+v^2$ in the denominators of $x^2$ and $y^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, you forgot to square denominators, so you *should* have
$$\frac{u^2+v^2}{(u^2+v^2)^2} = \frac{2u}{u^2+v^2}.$$
This simplifies to $2u=1$, as it should.